# Replace every n-th part of list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a list:

```
b = ConstantArray[1, 50];
```

And I would like to replace every say 5th element with 2: I came up with:

```
b[[;; ;; 5]] = b[[;; ;; 5]] /. {1 -> 2}
```

which works, but I do not like it much since it is very unflexible and simply ugly (repeating `b[[;; ;; 5]]`).

I was trying to make this work with `ReplacePart` but I am not sure how, I tried as per manual way to replace every even'th element:

```
ReplacePart[b, _?Mod[i_, 5]-> 2]
```

and also

```
ReplacePart[b, _?Mod[#, 5]&-> 2]
```

but they do not work. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: What's wrong with `b[[;; ;; 5]] = 2`? It is the fasted method that you will find.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Oh this is the way to avoid repetition... Thank you. Otherwise it is not very flexible as to setting the rules on which positions to replace (if the rule is more complicated, it will not work)

Comment: Your `ReplacePart` does not work because the syntax of the patterntest is incorrect. Try: `ReplacePart[b, _?(Mod[#, 5] == 0 &) -> 2]`. Part assignment is generally faster for full arrays, though.

Comment: Would it make sense to partition into sets of 5 and then perform a replacement on the last element of all sets then Flatten?

Answer (score 0):

This works, but its much slower than your method.

```
Table[If[Mod[i, 5] == 0, b[[i]] = 2], {i, Length[b]}]
```

but it might be easier to specify more complicated conditions.